# Parâmetro nulo em rota

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, parâmetros, rotas

Estou tentando entrar em um *controller*, receber um parâmetro e imprimi-lo na View por uma `ViewData` ou `ViewBag`.

Meu Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string information)
    {
        ViewData["Bag"] = information;
        return View();
    }
```

Minha View:

```
@ViewData["Bag"]
```

O problema é que o parâmetro `information` vem nulo sempre que passo na chamada de URL por exemplo: `http://localhost/Home/Index/teste`.

```
routes.MapRoute( name:"Default1", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Essa é a rota padrão.

Comment: você precisa desse parametro? se sim você pode colocar `string?` para permitir que este venha nulo para o controlador

Comment: eu preciso que pegue sim, mas quando coloco a url http://localhost/Home/Index/teste

asp.net-mvc ele deveria pegar a string information = "teste"

Comment: Como está o seu arquivo `RouteConfig`? Pergunto isso pois você postou a Action `index` de seu controller, e está acessando `Home/Index/Teste`. Se sua rota estiver errada, você precisa acessar assim: `Home/Index?information=Teste`

Comment: Acredito que seja da forma que o Randrade escreveu, que é o comportamento padrão de rota, assim você receberia o valor `Teste` para a variavel `information` corretamente em seu ActionResult.

Comment: a rota está  a padrão
routes.MapRoute(
                name:"Default1",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

Comment: Andre, cria um Model, adiciona a referência da Model na view e no controlador, preenche a Model. Deve funcionar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que sua rota padrão espera um parâmetro "id" e não um parâmetro "information".

Na action, troque o nome do parâmetro para "id" ou mude a sua rota para que receba um "information" e não um "id".

Answer (score 3):

Adicione uma nova rota, para não precisar modificar a `URI`.

```
routes.MapRoute( name:"Information", url: "{controller}/{action}/{information}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", information = string.Empty });
```

Adicionando esta rota o problema deve ser resolvido. Porém é valido lembrar que outra rota com um parâmetro `string` poderá ter problemas de roteamento.